# storing a pd.dataframe in excel; Error: file is not a zip file

Tags: excel, macos, openpyxl, python-zipfile

I have the following Code:

```
wb = load_workbook("ParisClimateAgreement.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    data = list(zip(K_0_1_series, r_series))
    df_a = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_a.columns = "Kapitalnachfrage Region 1", "whatever"
    df_a = pd.ExcelWriter("ParisClimateAgreement.xlsx")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ParisClimateAgreement.xlsx", mode="a", engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = wb
    df_a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Results")
    wb.save("ParisClimateAgreement.xlsx")
```

and get the following error:

File /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Uni-Unterlagen/Master VWL/2. Semester/Climate Modelling : Python/Dokumente_Python_Crashkurs/Kursmaterial/Session_9/ParisClimateAgreement.py:454
wb = load_workbook(r"ParisClimateAgreement.xlsx")

File openpyxl/reader/excel.pyc:344 in load_workbook

File openpyxl/reader/excel.pyc:123 in **init**

File openpyxl/reader/excel.pyc:95 in _validate_archive

File zipfile.pyc:1266 in **init**

File zipfile.pyc:1333 in _RealGetContents

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

The excel file is damaged afterwards. I already tried to create a new file with python but that doesnt work neither. And I already checked if I have installed the newest version of python and openpyxl. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the error or is there any other way to store my data in an excel file without using openpyxl?
(I am working on a Mac)